# input string was not in correct format C#.net

Tags: c#

```
 string selected= this.comboBoxitemno.GetItemText(this.comboBoxitemno.SelectedItem);
labelTesting.Text = selected;
int comboBoxitemno_temp = Convert.ToInt32(labelTesting.Text.ToString().Trim());
```

Still Error shows As follow [image]

Comment: Well yes, look at the value of `selected`... how would you expect to convert that into an `int`?

Comment: Probably you need to use SelectedValue in you ops. (After having set the DisplayMember and the DisplayValue when binding the combo to your DataTable of course)

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot, the value of `selected` is `"System.Data.DataRowView"`. This can't be converted to type `int`.

So your actual problem is in this line:

```
this.comboBoxitemno.GetItemText(this.comboBoxitemno.SelectedItem);
```

Instead of this line, you can use:

```
`this.comboBoxitemno.SelectedText;`
```